# Regarding Too many errors in /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1),

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, latex

Output of command on terminal at Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

sudo apt-get install python

```
   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:

....Many Lines are deleted......

dpkg: error processing package cm-super (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost:
 texlive-metapost depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context:
 context depends on texlive-metapost (>= 2013); however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.
 context depends on lmodern (>= 2.004.4); however:
  Package lmodern is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-gyre; however:
  Package tex-gyre is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context-modules:
 context-modules depends on context (>> 2011); however:
  Package context is not configured yet.
 context-modules depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
..... Many Lines are Deleted

dpkg: error processing package feynmf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcoNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                    lor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-common:
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-font-utils (>= 2007.dfsg.2-1); however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese:
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese:
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-japanese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-korean:
 latex-cjk-korean depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-korean depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-korean (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-other:
 texlive-lang-other depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-other (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-thai:
 latex-cjk-thai depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-lang-other (>= 2013.20130523-1); however:
  Package texlive-lang-other is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-thai (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-all:
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-japanese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-japanese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-korean (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-korean is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              thai (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-thai is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latexmk:
 latexmk depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latexmk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of m-tx:
 m-tx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package m-tx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of musixtex:
 musixtex depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package musixtex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pmx:
 pmx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 pmx depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pmx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of purifyeps:
 purifyeps depends on texlive-metapost; however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package purifyeps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-bibtex-extra:
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-bibtex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra:
 texlive-fonts-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-formats-extra:
 texlive-formats-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-formats-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-formats-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-polish:
 texlive-lang-polish depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-polish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-polish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-extra:
 texlive-generic-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-indic:
 texlive-lang-indic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-indic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-spanish:
 texlive-lang-spanish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-spanish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-omega:
 texlive-omega depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-omega depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-omega (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-cyrillic:
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-cyrillic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-humanities-doc:
 texlive-humanities-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-humanities-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-english:
 texlive-lang-english depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-english (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fragmaster:
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fragmaster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra-doc:
 texlive-latex-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-publishers-doc:
 texlive-publishers-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-publishers-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-european:
 texlive-lang-european depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-european (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pictures-doc:
 texlive-pictures-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pictures-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost-doc:
 texlive-metapost-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-science-doc:
 texlive-science-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-science-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-african:
 texlive-lang-african depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-african (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-math-extra:
 texlive-math-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-math-extra depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-math-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-math-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 latex-sanskrit
 lmodern
 tex-gyre
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-latex-recommended
 cm-super-minimal
 cm-super
 texlive-metapost
 context
 context-modules
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-extra-utils
 feynmf
 latex-xcolor
 latex-beamer
 latex-cjk-common
 latex-cjk-chinese
 latex-cjk-japanese
 latex-cjk-korean
 texlive-lang-other
 latex-cjk-thai
 latex-cjk-all
 latexmk
 m-tx
 musixtex
 pmx
 purifyeps
 texlive-bibtex-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 texlive-formats-extra
 texlive-lang-polish
 texlive-generic-extra
 texlive-lang-indic
 texlive-lang-spanish
 texlive-omega
 texlive-lang-cyrillic
 texlive-humanities-doc
 texlive-lang-english
 fragmaster
 texlive-latex-extra-doc
 texlive-publishers-doc
 texlive-lang-european
 texlive-pictures-doc
 texlive-metapost-doc
 texlive-science-doc
 texlive-lang-african
 texlive-math-extra
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And output of the code

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

is:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

And the output of the command

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

is:

```
# deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu precise main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
```

Also, when I tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

it ended with following thing

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 texlive-omega
 texlive-lang-french
 texlive-lang-other
 texlive-publishers
 texlive-lang-cyrillic
 texlive-metapost
 texlive-lang-german
 tex-gyre
 texlive-science
 texlive-latex-extra-doc
 texlive-science-doc
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc
 texlive-lang-english
 context-modules
 texlive-lang-european
 texlive-humanities-doc
 texlive-metapost-doc
 texlive-luatex
 texlive-generic-recommended
 texlive-pstricks-doc
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 latex-xcolor
 texlive-pictures
 texlive-fonts-extra
 context
 texlive-pictures-doc
 pmx
 latex-cjk-japanese
 texlive-formats-extra
 m-tx
 texlive-bibtex-extra
 latex-cjk-korean
 texlive-music
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc
 texlive-lang-spanish
 texlive-latex-recommended
 texlive-pstricks
 texlive-lang-african
 texlive-humanities
 texlive-math-extra
 texlive-lang-arabic
 texlive-lang-cjk
 texlive-full
 tipa
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-lang-czechslovak
 texlive-lang-italian
 texlive-lang-portuguese
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 latex-sanskrit
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Comment: Never mind the MaxReports warning, what were you trying to do? What was the command that caused this output? Please edit your question and add this info.

Comment: @Jos I have updated the question, actually while doing some update, a message flahed that it cannot update texlive correctly, after that I am facing this issue. That is on trying to install anything, it results into "Too many errors in /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: The usual solution is to try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and, if that works, `apt-get install -f`. Have you tried that?

Comment: check this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/603493/apt-get-dependency-issue-open-ssh-client

Comment: even after http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa, it does not help me

Comment: I have updated the output of different commands I have checked at the links you provided, but it didn't work till now. Also, I want to point out there is some problem with texlive installation, that you can see in the first dump for "sudo apt-get install python"

Answer (score 7):

Had very similar situation (even more packages in the list) after upgrading to 14.04.

Resolved by purging (maybe, just removing will do too) texlive-related packages and some stale files in /etc:

```
rm -Rf /etc/texmf/texmf.d
apt-get purge tex-common
apt-get purge texlive
apt-get purge texlive-*
```

Also, used

```
apt-get autoclean
dpkg --configure -a
```

to assess situation.

I do not yet need texlive, so I postponed it's reinstall for later time.

Hopefully, this will help someone doing upgrades from pre-14.04 to 14.04 and forward.

Comment: + 1 for you answer. I had a similar error with different packages running Pop-OS. `apt-get autoclean
dpkg --configure -a` worked for me.

Comment: `apt-get autoclean` only returns `E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the download directory`

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
 sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: Nope. `Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`