# apt-get dependency issue Open-SSH Client

Tags: apt, dependencies, openssh

This is on an Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

I'm getting this error when trying to run any `apt-get install` (trying to install unrelated, arbitrary packages):

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-server:
 openssh-server depends on openssh-client (= 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.1); however:
  Version of openssh-client on system is 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.4.
dpkg: error processing openssh-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency probms prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server; however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encounter while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Installing the client version in question leads to:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.1' for 'openssh-client' was not found
```

Various attempts to fix it with lack of background knowledge failed, e.g.

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
apt-get -f install
```

Can somebody give advice how to tackle the problem, possibly demanding more infos that are necessary from my side?

How can the openssh update (that I guess failed) be reverted or taken out of focus, so I am able to install other packages?

**Edit:**

Output of `apt-cache policy openssh-client` is:

```
openssh-client:
  Installed: 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.4
  Candidate: 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.4
  Version table:
 *** 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Just for completeness the `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: what does this output brings you? `apt-cache policy openssh-client` obviously you're trying to install some package that was not developed or tested with your current openssh-client

Comment: See output above as edit. I would rather not install the client, just want to get it cleared from apt conflicts to install other packages.

Comment: here you'll find all the detailed workarounds that you can apply http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Remove these packages, answer added

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just remove these packages to let you use `apt` for other packages.
Execute this commands in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client --purge && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get update
```

Then reinstall openssh server and client .

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the openssh-server, as I'm connected via ssh to this machine.

Comment: And just removing the client leads to the same dependency error.

Comment: remove server also then reinstall server and client

Comment: Removing ssh openssh-server and openssh-client and reinstall worked for me, thanks.

Comment: did not work for me. Still searching.

Comment: You may find that the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config is missing, you need to create it for some systems: sudo touch /etc/ssh/sshd_config if it isn't there.

Comment: Just like magic!  Does it work best to install them separately, instead of using `apt install ssh`?

Comment: @automorphic it doesn't matter whether you install them separately or in a single command

Answer (score 1):

When removing/purging openssh-server and openssh-client are not an option (for example when another package depends on them)

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```