# Many errors (I think dpkg related) after updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, apt, dpkg, error-handling

I had Ubuntu 16.04, and installed python 3.6 because there were some specific libraries that I wanted to use. Now, I tried to update to Ubuntu 18.04 and have **lots** of errors.

I had to use the Unity interface of 18.04 because Gnome would not let me log in. I can't open libreoffice, and many processes seem to be mucked up.

I tried to do some `apt` commands with no success in any: these include `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt autoremove`, `sudo apt -f install`, etc...

I've also tried to `dpkg --configure -a`, as stated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603486/regarding-too-many-errors-in-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1) with no success.

Here's the last part of the output for `sudo apt -f install` (or any of the aforementioned commands). The rest of the output (it's too big) can be found [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rm5F9NsTZV/).

```
    dependency problems prevent configuration of qmlscene:
 qmlscene depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Package libqt5gui5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qmlscene (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of baobab:
 baobab depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpango-1.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package baobab (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
 libqtgui4:amd64
 qt-at-spi:amd64
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-gtk2
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-base-drivers
 libqt5gui5:amd64
 libqt5svg5:amd64
 hud
 libpango-1.0-0:amd64
 libpango-1.0-0:i386
 gnome-disk-utility
 firefox
 libcogl-pango20:amd64
 gnome-initial-setup
 gedit
 libgail-3-0:amd64
 libido3-0.1-0:amd64
 libreoffice-report-builder
 qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64
 libreoffice-gtk3
 sni-qt:amd64
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
 compiz-gnome
 libunity-control-center1
 gstreamer1.0-x:amd64
 gnome-font-viewer
 libpango-perl
 unity-greeter
 texmaker
 librhythmbox-core10:amd64
 totem
 libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64
 libreoffice-gnome
 gnome-power-manager
 signon-ui-x11
 nautilus
 libreoffice-pdfimport
 libreoffice-gtk
 gnome-todo
 libgnomekbd8:amd64
 libreoffice-nlpsolver
 libgtk2-perl
 libclutter-1.0-0:amd64
 libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64
 evolution-data-server
 evince
 qmlscene
 baobab
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo apt -f install` yet? **Don't forget to review the output before you accept the changes** in case it wants to accidentally uninstall everything from your system. If the output seems reasonable, go ahead and accept it. Also, the last part doesn't really help as we would need to see the full output because you may have to start with the first one and manually configure it and then go down the line until it starts automatically configuring for you. If it is too long to post, you can post the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and then post a link in your answer or comment.

Comment: To message me back, just begin the comment with @mchid so that I will get a notification. Thanks!

Comment: @mchid Thanks for the prompt response! I've edited the my question and linked the whole error output--which was actually the output for `sudo apt -f install`. Hope it's more useful.

Comment: @mchid I managed to solve this issue by following method 4 of [this answer](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/): I saw that my problem first pointed to `fontconfig` (see my error output), so I `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i fontconfig` and then `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/fontconfig.* /tmp`. Not sure if this was a dangerous move, so I better not mark this as an answer until I'm sure. Now `apt` works for any command. Nevertheless, I have a new issue now: I can't open libreoffice. When I try to open `libreoffice` from terminal, I just get `Application Error` as an output.

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` please.  Post it to https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Sorry, I stepped away. Now, just reinstall fontconfig: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install --reinstall fontconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have fixed the main problem by running the command: `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/fontconfig.* /tmp` , you need to reinstall `fontconfig`.

First, run the following commands to reinstall `fontconfig`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall fontconfig
```

If that fails because it "cannot download" `fontconfig`, run the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall $(for i in $(dpkg -l | grep fontconfig | awk '{ print $2 }'); do echo "$i"=2.12.6-0ubuntu2; done)
```

Then, run the following commands to verify that 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 actually is the latest version:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep fontconfig | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

To explain: There was a "newer" version of the `fontconfig` packages "2.12.6-0ubuntu2.3" that was removed from the "proposed" repository so it is no longer available for download. In order to reinstall, we must downgrade to "2.12.6-0ubuntu2". These commands also downgrade any other `fontconfig` package that may be installed.